Anchor test error "InstructionDidNotDeserialize"
I wrote an instruction to remove mint authority,and meet "InstructionDidNotDeserialize" error when I tried to run anchor test.
Here is the instruction:
pub fn remove_mint_authority(ctx: Context<RemoveMintAuthority>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Removing mint authority...");

        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_accounts = SetAuthority {
            account_or_mint: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
            current_authority: ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info(),
        };

        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

        set_authority(
            cpi_ctx,
            AuthorityType::MintTokens,
            None, // Set the current mint authority to None, effectively destroying it.
        )?;

        msg!("Mint authority removed successfully.");

        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(bump: u8)]
pub struct RemoveMintAuthority<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint_account: Account<'info, Mint>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}


Here is the test file tests/test1.ts:
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program, BN, Provider, Wallet } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { PublicKey, Keypair, SystemProgram } from "@solana/web3.js";
import {NimbleV1} from "../target/types/nimble_v1.js";
import {setAuthority} from "@solana/spl-token";
import {
    getAssociatedTokenAddressSync, MINT_SIZE,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} from "@solana/spl-token";

describe("Create Tokens", () => {
    const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
    anchor.setProvider(provider);
    const connection = provider.connection


    const payer = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;
    const program = anchor.workspace.NimbleV1 as anchor.Program<NimbleV1>;
    //const program = new anchor.Program(anchor.workspace.NimbleV1,"5XCnsing3zjZBfbnxUVJJAtBxxMX5a7hoXUorhZSzbLt",provider);
    const [UsdcTokenMintPDA] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
        [Buffer.from("usdc")],
        program.programId
    )
    const UsdcTokenAccount = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
        UsdcTokenMintPDA,
        payer.publicKey
    )

    const usdcmetadata = {
        uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/program-examples/new-examples/tokens/tokens/.assets/spl-token.json",
        name: "usdc",
        symbol: "usdc",
    }

    // Generate new keypair to use as address for mint account.
    const mintKeypair = new Keypair();
    console.log("Mint Public Key:", mintKeypair.publicKey.toString());
    const metadata = {
        name: "Nimble Test Token 01",
        symbol: "NTT01",
        uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/program-examples/new-examples/tokens/tokens/.assets/spl-token.json",
    };

    console.log("Mint Public Key:", mintKeypair.publicKey.toString());

    it("Create an SPL Token!", async () => {
        // Derive metadata account (PDA)
        const [metadataPda, _bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
            [
                Buffer.from("metadata"),
                new PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s").toBuffer(),
                mintKeypair.publicKey.toBuffer(),
            ],
            new PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s") // Token Metadata Program ID
        );

        console.log("Create SPL token: Metadata Account (PDA):", metadataPda.toString());

        // SPL Token default = 6 decimals
        const transactionSignature = await program.methods
            .createCoin(metadata.name, metadata.symbol, metadata.uri)
            .accounts({
                payer: payer.publicKey,
                metadataAccount: metadataPda,
                mintAccount: mintKeypair.publicKey,
                tokenMetadataProgram: new PublicKey(
                    "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"
                ), // Token Metadata Program ID
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
                rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
            })
            .signers([mintKeypair])
            .rpc();

        console.log("Success!");
        console.log(`   Mint Address: ${mintKeypair.publicKey}`);
        console.log(`   Transaction Signature: ${transactionSignature}`);
    });

    it("3. Mint some tokens to your wallet!", async () => {
        console.log("Minting some tokens to your wallet...");
        // Derive the associated token address account for the mint and payer.
        const associatedTokenAccountAddress = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
            mintKeypair.publicKey,
            payer.publicKey
        );
        const amount = new BN(1000);

        // Mint the tokens to the associated token account.
        const transactionSignature = await program.methods
            .mintCoin(amount)
            .accounts({
                mintAuthority: payer.publicKey,
                recipient: payer.publicKey,
                mintAccount: mintKeypair.publicKey,
            })
            .rpc();

        console.log("Success!");
        console.log(
            `   Associated Token Account Address: ${associatedTokenAccountAddress}`
        );
        console.log(`   Transaction Signature: ${transactionSignature}`);
    });

    it("4. Remove mint authority!", async () => {
        console.log("Removing mint authority...");
        // Derive metadata account (PDA)
        const [metadataPda, _bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
            [
                Buffer.from("metadata"),
                new PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s").toBuffer(),
                mintKeypair.publicKey.toBuffer(),
            ],
            new PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s") // Token Metadata Program ID
        );

        console.log("Removing mint authority: Metadata Account (PDA):", metadataPda.toString());
        const transactionSignature = await program.methods
            .removeMintAuthority().accounts({
                authority: payer.publicKey,
                mintAccount: mintKeypair.publicKey,
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            })
            .rpc();

        console.log("Success!");
        console.log(`   Transaction Signature: ${transactionSignature}`);
    });
...

Successfully pass "Create an SPL Token!","Mint some tokens to your wallet",and meet
  1) Create Tokens
       4. Remove mint authority!:

 Error: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionDidNotDeserialize. Error Number: 102. Error Message: The program could not deserialize the given instruction.
      at Function.parse (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:136:14)
      at translateError (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:277:35)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:35:29)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)



This is what anchor test really execute:
<path-to-program>/node_modules/.bin/ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/test1.ts

Anchor-cli version is 0.30.1,solana-cli versioin is 1.18.26.
Here is the tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */
   "target": "es2016", 
    "module": "nodenext",   
    "esModuleInterop": true,                                     
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            
    "skipLibCheck": true  ,
    "strict": true,                                      
}
}

I would really appreciate any help! If you need to see more of my Rust/React JS code, please ask and I will share. Thank you.

If you use the #[instruction()] constraint on your Accounts struct, you need to pass value in your instruction as an argument.
pub fn remove_mint_authority(ctx: Context<RemoveMintAuthority>, bump: u8 ) -> Result<()> {
// -- snipe

sidenote, I don't see the use of the bump in your methods so it should be safe to remove it altogether.

Thanks! I will try your suggestion ;-)

Problem has been solved. Thanks again :-)

Be sure to mark the answer as "accepted" so that others can find the answer and to give Jimii the well-deserved points!
